# How to align bars from bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am developing a bar graph using react.
[image: This is the image of my bargraph]

The problem i am facing is that when given certain height the bars grow downwards instead of growing upwards.

This is css code for bar

```
.bar{
    width:20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 105px;
    z-index: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

this is css code for parent of bar

```
.nextB{
    height: 350px;
    width: 740px;
    border: 0px solid black;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-left: 265px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -376px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}
```

this is code for my bar component

```
import React from 'react';
import Classes from './barPart.css';
const barHandler= (props) =>(
    <div className={Classes.bar} style={{height: `${props.height}%`}}>
    </div>
);

export default barHandler;
```

Please provide me the correction that i have to make in my code to place my bars at the down end of the grey lines and let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `align-items: flex-end;` to make it work. Check out this example.

```css
.nextB{
    height: 100px;
    width: 340px;
    border: 0px solid black;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    align-items: flex-end; 
}

.bar{
    width:20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: 500;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nextB">
  <div class="bar" style="height:40px"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="height:60px"></div>
  <div class="bar" style="height:20px"></div>
</div>
```